# Stripe payment methods as a HTML data attribute best practise

Tags: html, stripe-payments

I am loading up the Stripe payment methods id as a HTML data attribute.

```
<option id="pm_id" data-pm-selected="pm_1HHYJ3Lq4MEyOT2kYKjE3tiO" value="pm_1HHYJ3Lq4MEyOT2kYKjE3tiO"> Card ending 4242 - Expires 2/2045 (Default Card)</option>
```

Is it good practice to load the payment method in this way or is there another way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? There are no specific problems I see with this, but it's tough to answer the question without more details about your objective.

Comment: Just asking if I should be loading payment method id via the data attribute. I am just loading previous payment methods here.